# PRISM WPF application Changing the ShellView background achieved as Grid background on Views added

Tags: wpf, prism

we have a PRISM WPF - MVP - application, we have the shell displaying the applicaton logo through the Grid.Background property. Now when a view is added on the main region the background looks so odd in the background. Since the view displayed on the shell is transparent this is happening. 
After a couple of brainstorming the only solution we have is to register for the RegionManager.Regions[MainRegion].Views.CollectionChanged event and in the event handler add logic such that : if No views are present in it then Ask the View to Display the background else ask it to Hide the background.

Is there any better alternative to it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "looks odd"? Some screenshots would be best

Comment: Sorry, i cannot share the actual screen! its like The background is White with an image.. now the view which has controls comes on the main region we could see the image logo in the gap between the controls. say between textbox and button of the view.

Comment: Can you set the Background of the View which contains controls to white?

Comment: yes, Rachel. its possible but it makes it look ugly as few of the views shown on the main region, like the search screens dont occupy the entire main region! hence we have it as Transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `MainRegion` is, but you could always just set it as a `Style`. This should work with some minor changes for any region, but here is an example if your MainRegion is just a `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        Title="Shell"
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">

    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                            Value="{StaticResource LogoBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Abe! On a curious note, Is there a way i could say if the MainRegion content is null show the background in XAML?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution that will work with ALL region types? The method I have shown requires no code behind...